# Codeception fails with "Module \Helper\Unit could not be found"?

Tags: php, phpunit, bitbucket, bamboo, codeception

im trying to set up old Bamboo Server (5.3) with codeception and php7.2. Created empty unit-test and light task - 'codecept run unit'; But it returns such a strange error:

```
build   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.22
build   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    Powered by PHPUnit 8.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    In ModuleContainer.php line 117:
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56                                                         
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56      Module \Helper\Unit could not be found and loaded  
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56                                                         
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    run [-o|--override OVERRIDE] [-e|--ext EXT] [--report] [--html [HTML]] [--xml [XML]] [--phpunit-xml [PHPUNIT-XML]] [--tap [TAP]] [--json [JSON]] [--colors] [--no-colors] [--silent] [--steps] [-d|--debug] [--bootstrap [BOOTSTRAP]] [--no-redirect] [--coverage [COVERAGE]] [--coverage-html [COVERAGE-HTML]] [--coverage-xml [COVERAGE-XML]] [--coverage-text [COVERAGE-TEXT]] [--coverage-crap4j [COVERAGE-CRAP4J]] [--coverage-cobertura [COVERAGE-COBERTURA]] [--coverage-phpunit [COVERAGE-PHPUNIT]] [--no-exit] [-g|--group GROUP] [-s|--skip SKIP] [-x|--skip-group SKIP-GROUP] [--env ENV] [-f|--fail-fast] [--no-rebuild] [--seed SEED] [--no-artifacts] [--] [<suite> [<test>]]
error   08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    
simple  08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    Failing task since return code of [/usr/local/bin/codecept run unit] was 1 while expected 0
simple  08-Dec-2021 15:55:56    Finished task 'codeception' with result: Failed
```

btw, \Helper\Unit - exists, and located in \tests_support\Helper

Comment: from the information you shared alone we can only guess at the problem. 
How is the Unit class included? What exactly happens in line 117? What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try to check mapping name space to directory structure.